# jQuery Accordion with jQuery.post and replace

Tags: jquery, accordion

So I am using jQuery accordion to collapse/expand "events": basically I get a bunch of youtube videos and put them in a div that expands on click.  However when I do so, half the screen turns black sometimes so I am wondering what is going on.  I am fine with a load animation or something showing in between, but not sure how to do that.

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    var thisDiv = $(this);
    if (thisDiv.parent()
               .next('.content:not(:empty)').text().length > 0)         
    {
        $.get('/videos', function(data) {
            thisDiv.parent().next('.content').html(data);
            $('#events').accordion();
        }); 
    }
});
```

Data coming back from /videos is youtube videos, so...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ALUxf1R0aXU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ALUxf1R0aXU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ALUxf1R0aXU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

...etc...

Is this the best way to do this?  I am replacing the .content div with the data coming back from the jQuery.get.... is this the best way to format this?  I realize that the videos coming back have to render but I am not sure how to handle that.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: What format is the data coming back from "/videos" in? HTML?

Comment: It is just a bunch of different youtube videos...
... added it to the top... 
I have it maxed at 15 right now, I would like to make it 10-15 minimum and then maybe a button for "more" that bring in the next 15, etc.

Comment: Are the videos ever being loaded while an accordion is minimized? I found I had a problem when trying to draw a graph that (and this is my own analysis) the accordion sets its contained divs to width/height of 0. Perhaps they aren't loading properly because when the accordion is collapsed, the div isn't valid to contain it.

Comment: @westo take a look here: http://tgcgrapes3.appspot.com/grapes it kind of goes bonkers after it loads the videos.  What is a better way to do this and why does the screen get all muffed up? I tried making sure it knows it is html by adding    function (data) {
          $(ui.newHeader[0]).next().html(data), 'html';
            });

Comment: @Perley only seems to so the black screen thing in Chrome... weird